# the trait bound `Event: From<pallet_base_fee::Event>` is not satisfied

Tags: parachain, frontier

I was trying to add Frontier template into my substrate-parachain-template project...

when I added this code below in runtime/src/lib.rs:

```
impl pallet_base_fee::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Threshold = BaseFeeThreshold;
    type IsActive = IsActive;
    type DefaultBaseFeePerGas = DefaultBaseFeePerGas;
}
```

I got this error:

```
    Compiling parachain-template-runtime v0.1.0 (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/runtime)
...
  error[E0277]: the trait bound `Event: From<pallet_base_fee::Event>` is not satisfied
     --> /mnt/sda3/polkadot/substrate-parachain-template-evm/runtime/src/lib.rs:525:15
      |
  525 |     type Event = Event;
      |                  ^^^^^ the trait `From<pallet_base_fee::Event>` is not implemented for `Event`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
                <Event as From<cumulus_pallet_dmp_queue::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<cumulus_pallet_xcm::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<frame_system::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<pallet_balances::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<pallet_collator_selection::Event<Runtime>>>
                <Event as From<pallet_ethereum::Event>>
              and 4 others
  note: required by a bound in `pallet_base_fee::Config::Event`
     --> /home/user2038/.cargo/git/checkouts/frontier-b733f450c86c5786/2e4daa4/frame/base-fee/src/lib.rs:49:15
      |
  49  |         type Event: From<Event> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
      |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `pallet_base_fee::Config::Event`

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

This `Event` has been used many times in runtime/src/lib.rs.

And those usage below are all working fine:

```
impl frame_system::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type Event = Event;
}

impl pallet_balances::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type Event = Event;
}
impl pallet_evm::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type Event = Event;
}

impl pallet_ethereum::Config for Runtime {
    ...
    type Event = Event;
}
```

So I do not know why `pallet_base_fee` cannot accept it...

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add pallet-base-fee in the `construct_runtime!` with `Event<T>`?

Comment: Adding `DynamicFee: pallet_dynamic_fee,` solves it. Thank you :)